# MediaWiki set createaccount user right

Tags: mediawiki

Just try to setup MediaWiki for fun but facing some no reaction for setting createaccount user right by following [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:User_rights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aUser_rights). When I set createaccount user right for anonymous, the MediaWiki provided a link to create users correctly. When I tried to set createaccount user right for logined user similarly, the MediaWiki didn't provide the link to create users.

Currently, only have one user inside user table, and its access right are 'syspos' and 'bureaucrat' in user_groups table.

In LocalSettings.php, set as following:

- $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
- $wgGroupPermissions['user']['createaccount'] = false;
- $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['createaccount'] = true;

Please feel free to point the mistakes I made, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Special:Createaccount link isn't shown to logged-in users by default. However, you can still navigate to Special:Createaccount to create an account with your sysop user.